# Linkedin Connection email address

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I want to fetch the email address of the users, who are in my connection, through linkedin connection api using PHP.

Does connection API support email address of the connections? If yes then please let me know how.

The api I used is at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

Comment: You should ask them => *Does connection API support email address of the connections?* Or look at the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API documentation (your link):

> For 1st degree connections, you may only 
>   retrieve profile fields available with the 
>   r_basicprofile member permission

This means you CANNOT get the email address.

Comment: Ya i read the whole page and me too had the same conclusion but I would like to know if anyone know secondary or other method to have the email.

Comment: If you are able to see the email address when you click around the site, you might be able to get somewhere by automating that process (using `cURL`) - otherwise I think you are out of luck.

Comment: I wonder if the [following link](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/not-able-authenticate-user-remailaddress-and-rwnus-scopes) would be of some help to you... If you can authenticate with `r_emailaddress` you may have better luck.

Comment: No matter how you authenticate you will not find an API to request email addresses of connections.